# What is the "see-saw exact sequence"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology

Let a connected linear algebraic group $G$ acts on an algebraic variety $X$, proper over a filed $k$.

In the proof of Proposition 1.5. of Mumford's GIT book, he says "....consider the see-saw exact sequence:
$0 \rightarrow H^1(\mathcal{O}_{G}^{\times}) \rightarrow H^1(\mathcal{O}_{G\times X}^{\times}) \rightarrow H^0(G, R^1 (p_1)_{\ast} (\mathcal{O}_{G\times X}^{\times}))$". I don't know "the see-saw exact sequence" and cannot find it on the web. What is it? Where are references of it?

Comment: I find a lot of references when googling the title, e.g., [here](https://www.math.utah.edu/dc/dc-lecture-notes.pdf), page $2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is "see-saw property". Are "see-saw property" and "see-saw exact sequence" same notion?